# servlet gives createSQLException

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have following code while executing in netbeans browser shows blank screen and can not move to the destination page

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class SignIn extends HttpServlet {



    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
       System.out.println("Signin Init");

    }

        public void destroy() {   }

       protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    System.out.println("Signin process");

        System.out.println("name="+request.getParameter("uname"));
        System.out.println("Password="+request.getParameter("pwd"));

       name=request.getParameter("uname");
       password=request.getParameter("pwd");
       System.out.println("name="+name);
     System.out.println("Password="+password);
       //code here for the validating of the user and if validated send them to the
       //myAccoutn.jsp
       //else send to the accountError.jsp

    try{   
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ERP");
         st=con.createStatement();
         System.out.println("---------------------in ConnectDB/n");
         System.out.println("-----------------before connect");
         System.out.println("-----------------after connect..."+con);
         System.out.println("-----------------create statemet");
         rs=st.executeQuery("select * from erplogin where name='"+name+"' and password='"+password+"'");
         System.out.println("-----------------qry exec");
         if(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("-----------------in If");
        int auth = rs.getInt("name");
System.out.println("-----------------getting auth"+auth);
       // session hass been created     
       session=request.getSession();
       session.setAttribute("uname", name);
       session.setAttribute("pwd",password);
       session.setAttribute("auth",new Integer(auth));

        /* TODO output your page here */
        response.sendRedirect("./MyAccount.jsp");

    }
else
      response.sendRedirect("./error/accountError.jsp");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Signin doGet");

        processRequest(request, response);
    }

          protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
      System.out.println("Signin doPost");

        processRequest(request, response);
    }

          public String getServletInfo() {
        return "User login";
    }
    private String name="";
    private String password="";
    HttpSession session;
    private boolean boolVal;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs=null;
    private Connection conObj;
    private static int errorVal=0;

}
```

which Gives following execution With Exception

```
Signin Init
Signin doPost
Signin process
name=aaa
Password=sss
name=aaa
Password=sss
---------------------in ConnectDB/n
-----------------before connect
-----------------after connect...sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection@4260ab
-----------------create statemet
-----------------qry exec
-----------------in If
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3811)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataInteger(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5638)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:583)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:601)
at SignIn.processRequest(SignIn.java:61)
at SignIn.doPost(SignIn.java:102)
```

at line

```
int auth = rs.getInt("name");
```

and

```
   processRequest(request, response);
```

please help me to solve these errors

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index` is obtained when you read the result set `rs` with incorrect index:

```
    int auth = rs.getInt(3);
```

Try to use the correct index,the column indexes start from `1` and so on. Maybe `3` doesn't an index of column.

Comment: and how to get out of the   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3811)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using index directly,you should use column name to get data.for example:suppose At first column name 'studentId'at index 0,then you can get correct answer by using like that int id = rs.getInt(0);but later your studentId column is changed to index number 2.then when you access int id = rs.getInt(0)then you will get wrong result or error.so it is safe to use column-name in rs.get().for eg:rs.getInt("studentId").that means even your column-name studentId change to any index,you can access data correctly.

Comment: It has solved problem of invalid descriptor but still  
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(JdbcOdbc.java:3811)
 At 

int auth = rs.getInt("name");
and
 processRequest(request, response);
on this lines

Comment: your column name 'name' type is int type?plz check data of column 'name'in table .if string exist in your column 'name'then it will get error:for eg:if your data is 'david' in column 'name',then you cannot call this data by using rs.getInt("name"),you must use rs.getString("name").

Comment: @Maddy,your problem is solved?please tell me what  your column 'name''s data type?

Comment: Problem is solved but encounter another one while login if successful then myaccount.jsp should open but instead accounterror.jsp is opened dont know why if statements went false and control moved to else block

Comment: @Maddy,you should debug in if block.

Comment: I have tried all possible option but not get satisfied just confused whether data is fetching from database or not